# Programa esperar resposta requisicao ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Galera, preciso fazer varias requisicoes ajax dentro de um loop e o programa so pode continuar depois que a requisicao for concluida. Estou usando o "async:false", porem ele trava a pagina toda enquanto aguarda o retorno. 
Alguem conhece alguma maneira do codigo so continuar depois da requisicao ser feita?

```
for(i=0; i<10;i++)   
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: link,
        async: false,
        success: function (e) { 
          var items = e.items;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          titulo = items[i].snippet.title; 
        }                           
    });
```

Comment: Isso não faz sentido. Você quer utilizar AJAX para fazer requisições síncronas? Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: Concordo completamente com o Anderson, ao invés de ver dessa forma tenta mudar a sua linha de raciocínio em relação aos elementos do form que necessitam desse retorno. Como montar de forma que a medida que vá recebendo a resposta pelo callback possa ir liberando as informações para o usuário.Ou poste o form aqui com mais detalhes para idéias.

Comment: O problema é que o loop FOR não pode continuar enquanto a requisicao nao for concluida. Isso por que a cada passada no loop eu preencho uma div com informações buscadas da requisicao e busco pela posicao do valor atual de i.